# How to hide broken image icon in PHP?

Tags: php, html, image, icons

```html
INSERT PICTURE IN DATABASE CODE:

if (!isset($_FILES['gambarid']['tmp_name'])) {
          echo "";
          }else{
      $rand5=rand(); 
    $image_name5= addslashes($_FILES['gambarid']['name']); 
    $fileext5=explode('.',$image_name5); $image_new5=$rand5;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["gambarid"]["tmp_name"],"images/gambarid/" . $image_new5 . $image_name5);
    $gambarid="images/gambarid/" . $image_new5 . $image_name5;
    }
    
    
         if (!isset($_FILES['icdepan']['tmp_name'])) {
         echo "";
         }else{
    $rand=rand(); 
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['icdepan']['name']); 
    $fileext=explode('.',$image_name); $image_new=$rand;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["icdepan"]["tmp_name"],"images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new . $image_name);
    $icdepan="images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new . $image_name;
    }
    
    if (!isset($_FILES['icbelakang']['tmp_name'])) {
         echo "";
         }else{
    $rand2=rand(); 
    $image_name2= addslashes($_FILES['icbelakang']['name']); 
    $fileext2=explode('.',$image_name2); $image_new2=$rand2;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["icbelakang"]["tmp_name"],"images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new2 . $image_name2);
    $icbelakang="images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new2 . $image_name2;    
    }
    
     if (!isset($_FILES['icatas']['tmp_name'])) {
         echo "";
         }else{
    $rand3=rand(); 
    $image_name3= addslashes($_FILES['icatas']['name']); 
    $fileext3=explode('.',$image_name3); $image_new3=$rand3;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["icatas"]["tmp_name"],"images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new3 . $image_name3);
    $icatas="images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new3 . $image_name3;
       
    }
    
    if (!isset($_FILES['icbawah']['tmp_name'])) {
         echo "";
         }else{
    $rand4=rand(); 
    $image_name4= addslashes($_FILES['icbawah']['name']); 
    $fileext4=explode('.',$image_name4); $image_new4=$rand4;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["icbawah"]["tmp_name"],"images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new4 . $image_name4);
    $icbawah="images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new4 . $image_name4;
    }
    
     if (!isset($_FILES['closeup1']['tmp_name'])) {
         echo "";
         }else{
    $rand6=rand(); 
    $image_name6= addslashes($_FILES['closeup1']['name']); 
    $fileext6=explode('.',$image_name6); $image_new6=$rand6;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["closeup1"]["tmp_name"],"images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new6 . $image_name6);
    $closeup1="images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new6 . $image_name6;
    }
    
     if (!isset($_FILES['closeup2']['tmp_name'])) {
         echo "";
         }else{
    $rand7=rand(); 
    $image_name7= addslashes($_FILES['closeup2']['name']); 
    $fileext7=explode('.',$image_name7); $image_new7=$rand7;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["closeup2"]["tmp_name"],"images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new7 . $image_name7);
    $closeup2="images/gambarkondisi/" . $image_new7 . $image_name7;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
 </head>
 <body>

<div class="container">
<div class="main">
</br></br>


<form action="" method="post">
<a href="#" onclick="window.print()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print List</a>

<table width="100%" border="0">

  <tr>
    <td width="20%" rowspan="2" align="left"><img src="images/logojmm.png" alt="logojmm" width="150" height="160" ></td>
    <td width="80%" colspan="2" align="right"><strong> Ref. No:     
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong><font size="6"> BAHAGIAN PENGURUSAN KONSERVASI</font> <br><br><font size="4">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    CONDITION REPORT</strong><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    PENILAIAN KONDISI</strong></font></td>
   </tr>
 </table> 
 
 <!-- <a data-toggle="modal" href="#student_delete" id="delete"  class="btn btn-danger" name=""><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a> -->
 <hr>
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border=1">
 
  <tbody>
  <?php
  // Connect to database server
      mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Select database
     mysql_select_db("dbinve") or die(mysql_error());

    // Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
     $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM konservasi WHERE id=" . $_GET["id"];
     $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

 
    // Loop the recordset $rs
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  ?>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b><center>SEKSYEN A - PENGENALAN ARTIFAK</center></b></td>
        </tr>
        
  <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>TARIKH PENILAIAN:</b></td> 
  <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['tarikh']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>LOKASI PENILAIAN:</b></td> 
  <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['lokasi']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>NO. PENDAFTARAN:</b></td> 
  <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['nopendaftaran']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>NAMA ARTIFAK:</b></td> 
  <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['namaartifak']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>SUMBER KOLEKSI:</b></td> 
  <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['sumber']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>SUMBER PINJAMAN : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['sumberpinjaman']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>LAIN-LAIN SUMBER : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['lainlainsumber']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>KATEGORI ARTIFAK: </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['kategori']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><b>UKURAN</b></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>PANJANG: </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['panjang']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>TINGGI : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['tinggi']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>LEBAR: </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['lebar']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>DIAMETER: </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['diameter']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>MAKLUMAT TAMBAHAN ARTIFAK: </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['maklumattambahanartifak']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
   
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b><center>SEKSYEN B- KONDISI ARTIFAK</center></b></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>JENIS KOLEKSI : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['koleksi']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>LAIN-LAIN KOLEKSI : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['lainlainkoleksi']; ?></td> 
        </tr>   
        </table>
        
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border=1">
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b><center>JENIS KEROSKAN</center></b></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><b><center>Kerosakan Struktur</center></b></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b><center>Kerosakan Permukaan</center></b></td>
        </tr>
 
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Tiada Kerosakan Struktur : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['tiadakerosakan1']; ?></td>
        <td width="40%"><b>Tiada Kerosakan Permukaan : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['tiadakerosakan2']; ?></td>  
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Retak : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['retak']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Calar : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['calar']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Patah : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['patah']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Mengelupas : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['mengelupas']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Hilang : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['hilang']; ?></td>
        <td width="40%"><b>Melepuh  : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['melepuh']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Bengkok : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['bengkok']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Pudar  : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['pudar']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Sumbing : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['sumbing']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Kotor : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['kotor']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>  
        <td width="40%"><b>Longgar : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['longgar']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Karat : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['karat']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Lubang Kecil : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['lubangkecil']; ?></td>
        <td width="40%"><b>Lipatan  : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['lipatan']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Rapuh : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['rapuh']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Kemek: </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['kemek']; ?></td>       
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Mengecut : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['mengecut']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Kulat : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['kulat']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Kesan konservasi : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['kesankonservasi']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Kusam : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['kusam']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Jumlah Kerosakan Struktur (%) : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['jumlahstruktur']; ?></td> 
        <td width="40%"><b>Jumlah Kerosakan Permukaan (%) : </b></td> 
        <td width="10%"><?php echo $row['jumlahpermukaan']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3" width="90%"><b><center>Kerosakan Keseluruhan (%)</center></b></td>
        <td colspan="1" width="10%"><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="1" width="40%"><b><center>Kondisi Artifak</center></b></td>
        <td colspan="3" width="60%"><?php echo $row['gred']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="1" width="40%"><b><center>Maklumat Tambahan Kerosakan:</center></b></td>
        <td colspan="3" width="60%"><?php echo $row['maklumattambahankerosakan']; ?></td>
        </tr> 
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b><center>GAMBAR ARTIFAK</center></b></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="1" width="40%"><b><center>Gambar ID :</center></b></td>
        <td colspan="3" width="60%">Nota : <?php echo $row['gambaridnota']; ?> <br><br>
                                     <center><?php echo "<img src='".$row['gambarid']. "' height='300px' 
             width='300px'/>";?></center>
        </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b><center>BAHAGIAN-BAHAGIAN OBJEK</center></b></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="50%"><center><b>DEPAN</b></center> <br>
        
                                    Keterangan : <?php echo $row['keterangandepan']; ?> <br><br>
                                    <center><?php echo "<img src='".$row['depan']. "' height='300px' 
             width='300px'/>";?></center>
        <td colspan="2" width="50%"><center><b>BELAKANG </b></center><br>
        
                                    Keterangan : <?php echo $row['keteranganbelakang']; ?> <br><br>
                                    <center><?php echo "<img src='".$row['belakang']. "' height='300px' 
             width='300px'/>";?></center>
        </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="50%"><center><b>ATAS</b></center> <br>
        
                                    Keterangan : <?php echo $row['keteranganatas']; ?> <br><br>
                                    <center><?php echo "<img src='".$row['atas']. "' height='300px' 
             width='300px'/>";?></center>
        <td colspan="2" width="50%"><center><b>BAWAH </b></center><br>
        
                                    Keterangan : <?php echo $row['keteranganbawah']; ?> <br><br>
                                    <center><?php echo "<img src='".$row['bawah']. "' height='300px' 
             width='300px'/>";?></center>
        </td>
        </tr>    
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="50%"><center><b>Gambar Close Up 1</b></center> <br>
        
                                    Keterangan : <?php echo $row['keterangancloseup1']; ?> <br><br>
                                    <center><?php echo "<img src='".$row['closeup1']. "' height='300px' 
             width='300px'/>";?></center>
        <td colspan="2" width="50%"><center><b>Gambar Close Up 2</b></center><br>
        
                                    Keterangan : <?php echo $row['keterangancloseup2']; ?> <br><br>
                                    <center><?php echo "<img src='".$row['closeup2']. "' height='300px' 
             width='300px'/>";?></center>
        </td>
        </tr>         
             
       </table>
        
        
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border=1">
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b><center>SEKSYEN C- CADANGAN RAWATAN/TINDAKAN KONSERVASI</center></b></td>
        </tr>
       
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Cadangan Rawatan : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['rawatan']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Lain-lain Rawatan : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['lainlainrawatan']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b><center>LAPORAN DISEDIAKAN OLEH</center></b></td>
        </tr>
        
         <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Nama Pegawai 1 : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['pegawai1']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td width="40%"><b>Nama Pegawai 2 : </b></td> 
        <td width="60%"><?php echo $row['pegawai2']; ?></td> 
        </tr>
  
     
        <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
        
        <tr>
        <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b><center>KONDISI OBJEK DIPERIKSA OLEH</center></b></td>
        </tr>
     
        <tr>
        <td width="102" rowspan="2" valign="top"><center><p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>RECEIVE/</strong><br><i>Penerimaan</i></p>
        </center></td>
        <td width="236" rowspan="2" valign="top">
        <center><p><strong>CONDITION UPON UNPACKING</strong></center></strong>
        o <strong>Condition Unchange</strong>/ Tiada Perubahan<br>
        o <strong>Condition Change</strong>/ Berubah</p></td>
        <td width="142" valign="top"><center><p><strong></strong></p></center></td>
        <td width="137" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="142" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
        <td width="137" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="102" rowspan="4" valign="top"><center><p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p><strong>RETURN/</strong><br><i>Pemulangan</i></p>
        </center></td>
        <td width="236" rowspan="2" valign="top">
        <center><p><strong>CONDITION UPON REPACKING</strong></center></strong>
        o <strong>Condition Unchange</strong>/ Tiada Perubahan<br>
        o <strong>Condition Change</strong>/ Berubah</p></td></td>
        <td width="137" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
        <td width="215" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="142" valign="top"><center><p><strong></strong></p></center></td>
        <td width="137" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="236" rowspan="2" valign="top">
        <center><p><strong>CONDITION UPON UNPACKING</strong></center></strong>
        o <strong>Condition Unchange</strong>/ Tiada Perubahan<br>
        o <strong>Condition Change</strong>/ Berubah</p></td></td>
        <td width="137" valign="top"><center><p><strong></strong></p></center></td>
        <td width="215" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="142" valign="top"><center><p><strong></strong></p></center></td>
        <td width="137" valign="top"><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="form7.php">Return to the list</a></p> 
    
 
  <?php } ?>   
  </tbody>
 </form>
```

I'm doing simple registration system. Here I attached the picture before and after upload picture and retrieve from database.

My question is in my form got few upload picture buttons and not all pictures are uploaded everytime. So in my report, I can see all the pictures I uploaded and I also see the broken image picture also because some picture not uploaded.

So how to hide broken image icon?

[broken image picture icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAyxT.png)

Comment: add your code...

Comment: We can help you but you need to add you codes so we can have a look.

Comment: You can use `file_exists()`.

Comment: yes done pls see my codes

Comment: $img = "defaultimg.jpg"; 
   if(file_exists("profilepic/".$_SESSION['userName'].".jpg")){
    $img = "profilepic/".$_SESSION['userName'].".jpg"; 
   }
  
  
  echo'<p align="right"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="' . $img .'" width="100px" height="100px"</p>';

Comment: Tell us how you store the image in database? do you store the path to the image file or you store the image as a blob.

Comment: @ThillaiKumaran : as suggested by sougata Bose , first check whether file is exists or not in that folder

Comment: What server are you using? Maybe with mod_rewrite if the requested resource isn't present you can serve default image.

Answer (score 0):

You can load default image when image not found using onerror,

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='default.jpg';" />
```

you can also hide image by following code,

```
<img onerror='this.style.display = "none"'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this assuming you store the image path in data base not the image itself.

You can archive what you want by using `file_exists()` and CSS look at the code below.

Code:

```
<?php $path = "../image/".$row['closeup1'] ?>
<td colspan="2" width="50%"><center><b>Gambar Close Up 1</b></center> <br>        
Keterangan : <?php echo $row['keterangancloseup1']; ?> <br><br>
<center>
<img src='".$path. "' height='300px' width='300px' <?php if(file_exists($path)){ echo "style='display:inline;'"}else{echo "style='display:none;'"} />";?>
</center>
```